Elavon Converge Hosted Payment Page Call back URL not being hit
I am using Elavon converge's hosted payments page integration method. https://developer.elavon.com/products/converge/v1/hosted-payments
I am able to successfully get a session token and redirect to a payment page using it. Now, I want to setup a webhook that consumes the result of the transaction, so I can maintain/process the payment internally.
I am running a simple dummy python http.server on my local and using ngrok to get a public url for this server.
Now, the problem is it is unclear how to specify the call back webhook. https://developer.elavonpaymentgateway.com/#!/hpp/transaction-processing This page talks about it but seems outdated and not specific to the new hosted payment page integration method.
https://developer.elavon.com/products/converge/v1/supported-transaction-input-fields
This page mentions a param named ssl_callback_url but adding this param to my transaction_token call doesn't do anything. I want to hear back the response of my transaction to my local server.
I have tried adding ssl_callback_url parameter to my session token call. I have also tried adding the url to the converge portal under export settings but that doesn't work either.

did you find the solution for this? if you can share it it will be great cz I'm having same scenario
